# Why does BizTalk WCF Lob adapter SDK is not getting installed on Windows 10 machine?

Tags: installation, biztalk, wcf-lob-adapter

I am installing BizTalk server on my Windows 10 machine. I have two visual studio instances installed. One is VS2015 and other one is VS2017. I could install the BizTalk server 2016 successfully and could create and use some of its components. However, now I want to use WCF Adapter as well. For this, I was trying install Microsoft WCF Lob Adapter SDK through the installation setup. But it is failing to install saying "A non up-gradable version of WCF Lob Adapter SDK already exists. installation can not continue. Remove existing WCF Lob Adapter SDK through Add/Remove programs and try installing again!".

[image]

I tried to uninstall all the adapter packs that were installed and reinstall WCF Lob Adapter SDK. But got no luck.

Does any one has an idea about this?
I am new to BizTalk and trying to learn the administration. Could anyone help me out?

Comment: Is the BizTalk installation the Developer Edition?

Comment: Yes. It is showing its an Evaluation version.

Comment: Are there any other WCF components listed in Add/Remove Programs?

Comment: I don't find any of them in Add/Remove programs.